# Change text of legend in Chart?

Tags: c#, .net, visual-studio-2010, charts

Please see my example for the chart

[image]

Now, I am want to change text of the legends (don't show percent value) same as xValues of series data, such as: London, Tokyo, Paris,... (Still keep percent values in the pie).

Do you know how to do that ?

I used below codes:

```
int[] yValues = { 50, 20, 10, 20 }; 
string[] xValues = { "London", "Paris", "Newyork", "Tokyo"};

myChart.Series["Default"].Points.DataBindXY(xValues, yValues);
myChart.Series[0].Label = "#PERCENT{P2}";
```

Answer (score 8):

I found the answer by using below codes:

```
myChart.Series["Default"].Label = "#PERCENT";
myChart.Series[0].LegendText = "#VALX";
```

Comment: this didnt work for me, i am adding data like this `Series1.Points.AddXY("Paid", 8500)`

Answer (score 5):

No need for a hack, this is all built-in:

[image]

```
Series s = chart1.Series.Add("Pie");
s.ChartType = SeriesChartType.Pie;
s.IsValueShownAsLabel = true;

s.Points.AddXY(0, 12);
s.Points.AddXY(1, 22);
s.Points.AddXY(2, 42);

s.Points[0].LegendText = "wo";
s.Points[1].LegendText = "wa";
s.Points[2].LegendText = "wi";
```

Comment: This should be the best answer. A pie has just a few points and it's so easy to access them one by one.

Comment: At what point do I add the `...LegendText`? It doesn't show up in my chart for some reason.

Comment: It really doesn't matter, as long as the DataPoints are in place. Note the __fundamantal difference between Pie and all other charttypes__: For Pie the Legend will show some text for each Point, for all other types it will show series related text!

Answer (score 4):

This is quite a hack, I hope you have a good reason for wanting this.  You hook into the CustomizeLegend event:

```
private void myChart_CustomizeLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
    foreach (LegendItem LI in e.LegendItems)
    {
        LI.Cells[1].Text = LI.Cells[1].Text.Replace('%', ' ');            
    }
}
```

Another version in case you wanted the city names.  Please add error handling:

```
private void myChart_CustomizeLegend(object sender, CustomizeLegendEventArgs e)
{
    string[] xValues = { "London", "Paris", "Newyork", "Tokyo" };

    for (int i = 0; i < e.LegendItems.Count; i++)
    {
        e.LegendItems[i].Cells[1].Text = xValues[i];
    }
}
```